# How can I add a local library as a dependency in Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift

How can I add a local library (a *.a file) as a dependency in Swift Package Manager?

I try adding in my Package.swift:

```
dependencies: [
    // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.,
    .package(url: "file://../otherdirectory/x86_64-apple-macosx/debug/libTest.a")
],
```

But I get this error when I run 'swift build'

```
Package.swift:17:10: error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First: `package` dependency can link to other packages only!

It's possible from **Swift 5.3** with `binaryTarget` but you should build your static library with several needed architectures(arm64, x86_64) and then create XCFramework from them with next command:

```sh
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
    -library <path> [-headers <path>] \
    [-library <path> [-headers <path>]...] \
    -output <path>
```

e.g.:

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
    -library build/simulators/libMyStaticLib.a \
    -library build/devices/libMyStaticLib.a \
    -output build/MyStaticLib.xcframework
```

Then you can create new binary target dependency in your package:

```swift
let package = Package(
   name: "MyPackage",
   ...
   targets: [
      .target(
         name: "MyPackage",
         dependencies: ["MyStaticLib"]
      ),
      .binaryTarget(name: "MyStaticLib", path: "path/MyStaticLib.xcframework"),
      ...
   ]
```

Note: The path to xcframework starts from the root of the project (same as Package.swift).

Comment: Here's a link to the supporting Apple Developer documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/distributing_binary_frameworks_as_swift_packages