# Exporting Package.swift for Swift Package Manager from existing Xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, core-data, swift-package-manager

I'm working with Xcode 11.3 on macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

I have an existing Xcode project which builds an app for iOS. I am interested in reusing some of the classes in an interactive session with the `swift` command line interpreter. The classes I want to work with are Core Data classes which are autogenerated from an Xcode data model and also some classes I've written which work with the Core Data classes. The app has UI screens and makes use of UIKit but I'm not trying to use any of those classes; I'm hoping that I can either compile those classes and then not refer to them, or somehow tell Swift Package Manager to ignore those classes altogether.

What I think I would like to do is to export a Package.swift for the existing Xcode project, such that `swift build` at the command line would be able to compile all of the project classes, or, failing that, at least the non-UI classes, and then `swift run --repl` would be able to load the classes via `import`.

I see a menu item in Xcode to create a new Swift package, but not to export an existing project. Is there a way to export an existing project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no a menu command or utility to convert application to a static library, dynamic framework or swift package since they are different types of projects with different settings etc.

If you want to export a part of your project as a swift package you should make next steps manually:

**1. Create Package.swift file in the root of your project**

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: “MyLib”,
    products: [
        .library(name: "MyLib", targets: ["MyLib"])
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "MyLib"),
    ],
    ...
)
```

**2.  Make folder with subfolder `./Sources/MyLib` under the projects’s root.**

By default swift package structure requires to put all your sources files under Sources/`LibraryName` folder but you can change it below.

NOTE: you can simplify first two steps by using `swift package init` and it creates Package.swift, Sources and Test folders etc.

**3. Include source files**

a) Move the needed files to share from their current locations to MyLib folder.

For instance:

```
./Classes/MyEntity.swift -> ./Sources/MyLib/MyEntity.swift
```

Also you have to update locations of the moved files in your Xcode project to leave it compilable.

b) Use `path`, `sources` and `exclude` to point needed source files to your package from their current locations:

```
.target(name: "MyLib", path: "Classes"),
```

NOTE: Don't forget to make your classes public to access to them after import your package:

```
public class MyEntity {
...
}
```

After all you will have two working projects - old XCode's one  and new Swift package.

**4. REPL**

Now you can use command line interpreter with your swift package:

```
swift run --repl
import MyLib
let entity = MyEntity()
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a few questions. (1) The existing project manages external dependencies via Cocoapods. Is there a way to extract the list of dependencies from the Podfile in a form which can be imported into Package.swift? I guess I can do that by hand but I wonder if it's possible to automate it. (2) Is there any special consideration for Core Data? The existing project makes use of auto-generated classes for Core Data entities which are somewhere under $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. I wonder how those would be brought into the project. Thanks again!

Comment: 1) About cocoapods see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63700091/using-a-pod-from-inside-a-swift-package/63713743#63713743

Comment: 2) CoreData:  You can disable Codegen=Manual/None for your entities and have own managed classes in the project which can be moved to the swift package’s folder or just copy auto generated files to swift package.
For Xcode 11/Swift 5.2 you can not include model files to swift package but you can create a model programmatically (https://medium.com/@dmytro.anokhin/core-data-and-swift-package-manager-6ed9ff70921a). For Xcode 12/Swift 5.3 is possible to add a Core Data model resources (https://useyourloaf.com/blog/add-resources-to-swift-packages/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this additional information. Looks like I have a lot to go on. One final question, is it possible to have the source code somewhere other than Sources/packagename? Ideally I would keep the same directory structure as in the existing Xcode project, but I'll change it if need be.

Comment: Yes it's possible, you can play with `sources`, `path` and `exclude` under the target, see my update for 3 (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/target/2880335-path)